# Solving system of differential equations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to solve RLC circuits using python.
When there are no Cs and Ls, after calculating i got to a linear system of equations which i solved using `numpy.linalg`, e.g :

```
a + b = 1
a + c = 2
c - b = 1
```

But now i need to solve this with differential elements in it.
I know that i probably should use `scipy` and i read the docs and other Qs about solving non-linear system of equations but i couldn't find anything helpful.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is better if you edit your post to include even the differential equations